# Removing last 10 lines of each RMarkdown in a folder

Tags: r, r-markdown

I wish to run a R script where I can remove the last 10 lines of each Rmarkdown file as the last 10 lines are confidential content. I have been given 10 such RMarkdowns in total. Is there a better way to do this than doing it one by one?

I have provieded a dummy tempalte of the Rmarkdown.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Unknown"
date: "28/05/2021"
output: pdf_document
---


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:


## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:


Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:


Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:


Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:


Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `readLines`and `writeLines`for this:

```
txt <- readLines("test.md")
N <- length(txt)
writeLines(txt[1:(N-10)], "test_short.md")
```

Then use `dir`to enumerate all files and automate with `lapply` or a `for` loop.

Comment: Or shorter `writeLines(head(readLines("test.md"), -10),"test_short.md")`